# Matlab access directory

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the comparison between my Ground Truth and Segmentation result, both were saved in different directory in `main_folder`, and I want to access it, but it seemed that I can't access the data inside the directory. Can someone help me whats wrong with the code.

Here is the code :

```
addpath('main')
currentDir=pwd; % current directory in main_folder 
cases=dir('Casos_img');
interp=1;
ori=1;
ASMvGT=zeros(0,1);
for c=3:size(cases,1)
     caseName=cases(c).name;
     gt_case=[currentDir '\Casos_combine\' cases(c).name]; %'
     % ground truth combined
     [~,~,~,volumeL,volumeR]=load_file(gt_case,0,ori);
     ind= volumeR>0;volumeGT=volumeL;volumeGT(ind)=1;
     [GT1 GT2 GT3]=ind2sub(size(volumeGT),find(volumeGT>0));GT=[GT1 GT2 GT3];

     segm_case=[currentDir '\Casos_img\' cases(c).name]; %'
     [~,~,~,volumeL,volumeR]=load_file(segm_case,0,0);
     ind= volumeR>0;volumeS=volumeL;volumeS(ind)=1;
     [ASM1 ASM2 ASM3]=ind2sub(size(volumeS),find(volumeS>0));ASM=[ASM1 ASM2 ASM3];

     [hd,~]=HausdorffDist(GT,ASM);
     ASMvGT=[ASMvGT;hd];%/numel(volumeGT)];

end
save resultshd ASMvGT
```

I can't get the volume with load_file function, because when I debug it the problem is I can't acces the data inside the directory. Please help me with this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use `chdir` and `fullfile` command to create file names with full paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addpath(genpath("___address of main_folder___"))`

Put the address of your main folder above. Replace the first line of your code with above line. You have only written `addpath('main')`. Therefore, it does not add subfolders and thats why probably you are getting error. `genpath` creates list of subfolders and thus if you combine `addpath` and `genpath`, the current folder as well as all of its subfolders will get added.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working, I will explain about the structure of the folder.

main_folder and inside that there are folder Casos_combine and Casos_img, I need to access the data inside both of the subfolder. 
Addpath('main') I'm using that because inside the folder main I have function that I need to be called. 

Can you help me, how I can access the subfolder Casos_combine and Casos_img?

Comment: use `addpath(genpath('____full path of main folder____'))`. Otherwise, simplest way would be to go to MATLAB command window, see on the left hand side, you will see your current directory of MATLAB. Right click on `Casos_combine` and `Casos_img` and say `add with subfolders`